# Как запустить внешнюю программу из текущей на языке С linux

Tags: linux, c, сервер

Суть проблемы: есть два взаимодействующих сервера. Первый открывает и биндит порты, второй коннектится к ним.  Запускаются сейчас в отдельных терминалах. Как можно из первого сервера открыть и забиндить порты, а потом запустить второй? Пробовала fork,  и внутри вот так использовать execl:
внутри функции open_port

```
if(fork() == 0){ 
        // Child process
        execl("python3", "my_second_server.py", 0);
        exit(0);
}else
{
        // Parent process code for connection and bind 
}
```

Но кажется второй так и не запустился..

Comment: Смотрим прототип функции: `execl(<shell path>, arg0, file, arg1, ..., (char *)0)`. `shell path = "python3"` - вопросов нет. `arg0 = "python3" полный путь исполняемого файла`. `file = "my_second_server.py"` - скармливаем скрипт питону. Получаем `execl("python3", "python3", "my_second_server.py", (char *)0);`

Comment: `execl` нужно передавать полный путь до исполняемого файла (например, `/usr/bin/python3`), для поиска имени в PATH подобно оболочке используй `execlp()`, также нулевым аргументом должно идти имя программы, например, `python3` ... кроме того удостоверься, что буть к самому скрипту правильный... и, в третьих, добавляй контроль ошибок к каждому системному вызову — оно поможет определить, в чём проблема...

Answer (score 0):

Если просто в лоб, то можно вот так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const char *command) 
{
     system("python3 ~/python.py ");

     return 0;
}
```